# "Comment edited" icon is too prominent

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, design, comment-edits

I noticed this yesterday:

> [image]

The "this comment was edited" pencil icon became fully black, which makes it very prominent and draws too much attention to it, in my opinion.

I'm pretty sure it used to be gray before.

Can it please become gray again?

Comment: Also reported on MSO [The edited icon is too prominent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371313/the-edited-icon-is-too-prominent).

Comment: @ale well, that's something only you see for actions you did, and it's much more rare than editing, so pretty minor.

Comment: On an edited comment on this page, it looks like it's the same gray as the timestamp (which is different from your screenshot).  Are you still seeing the dark icon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've added a tiny bit of opacity to this icon. We've switched from static pngs to SVG that inherits the text color. This is important for theming flexibility. It's now a bit more subtle by default ✌️.

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's better as the darker, more obvious edit symbol. The point of it is to draw a persons attention and alert them that there may be new content they missed on the first read-through. It's quite common that when people are going back and forth (which should be done in chat, but it happens in comments too), someone might edit their comment AS the other person is already responding to the unedited one. Once their done, a nice clear edit symbol is the most efficient way for them to see that they should reread it (maybe except for the comment being double the length, but that isn't always the case).

So that is one big reason FOR having the obvious symbol. I can't think of any reason not to.